# Prove that if $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} = L < 1$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence with $x_n > 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. I would like a hint on how to prove that if $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} = L < 1$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = 0$.

Here is what i have tried. There exist a $N$ such that $|\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} - L| < \varepsilon$ for all $n \geq N$. From this i must conclude that for some $M$ we have $|x_n|<\varepsilon$ for $n \geq M$. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I suspect i need some smart trick.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

How about this reverse argument: since $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_{n+1}/x_n=L<1$, then, by the ratio test, the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n < \infty
$$
That gives 
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=0
$$

Comment: *Reverse* argument, rather than *direct*, since the ratio test is based on the result this question asks to prove.

Comment: @Did, that's what I tought, although we can prove the ratio test whitout this result. I put it this way, since the OP did not specify if he already know the ratio test.

Comment: "we can prove the ratio test whitout this result" Hmmm... how?

Comment: @Did, for example by proving that the series is absolutely convergent. See http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test for the outline of the proof

Comment: The proof of the ratio test in the link uses exactly this result.

Comment: How exactly does the proof of the ratio test use $x_n\to 0$?

Comment: I agree with @zhw , I don't see it.

Comment: @Did can you enlighten us how the link proof uses that $ x_n \to 0$ ?

Comment: @zhw. and OP: In the linked proof of the ratio test, the idea is to "show that the series converges absolutely by showing that its terms will eventually become less than those of a certain convergent geometric series". Thus, the proof of the ratio test shows that the series converges and that $x_n\to0$ since $(x_n)$ is bounded by the terms of a convergent geometric sequence. Thus, to appeal to the ratio test to show that the hypothesis of the ratio test implies that $x_n\to0$ amounts to take for granted a result which is more elaborate than the desired one, rather basic.

Comment: @Did, I see your point. However, by showing first the series converges it is automatically implied that $x_n \to 0$, thus strictly the proof of the ratio test does not uses that $x_n \to 0$, it is merely a consequence.

Comment: Although you may see this question as a desguised ratio test, and then of course it won't be correct to use it. But again since the OP did not tell us he was proving the ratio test, then using it is a valid approach. @Did

Comment: Precisely: *appealing to the ratio test is to take the desired result for granted* by appealing to a strictly stronger result.

Comment: @Did, you will agree that this result is a corollary of the ratio test. Then as a corollary it may be prove by appeling to a previous known theorem. I insist, the thing here changes if the OP was or wasn't proving the ratio test, which I think he was not.

Comment: Quote: **simpler**.

Comment: Well, in my opinion Did has a point... but I don't agree that the ratio test depends on this, as he says. It "comes off" in the proof of the ratio test, but the fact by itself is of no use in the test: knowing it makes no difference for the proof. It is the same as saying that we use the fact that $a_n \rightarrow 0$ to prove the cauchy criterion for series. Nevertheless, I agree that using a strictly more powerful result that "spits out" what you want to prove is not advisable, even more because OP is probably getting introduced to analysis.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo well said. As I said before it all comes to the OP knowdledge. I remember once in a test, using this criterion to prove that $n!/n^n \to 0$, my way of tought was exactly by using the ratio test.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the limit exists, and is different than $0$. Let's call it $x$. Then, $\lim \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}=\frac{x}{x}=1<1$. We have arrived at a contradition.

Therefore, if it exists, it is $0$.

Pick $L<\gamma<1$. Therefore, there exists $N$ such that for all $n>N$, $x_{n+1}<\gamma x_n<x_n$. We then have the sequence is decreasing after $N$. But if it is decreasing and bounded, it converges.

We can summarize the argument as follows:

> Okay, let's suppose the limit exists. Then it must be $0$. But the sequence is eventually monotonic and bounded. Therefore, it exists, and is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $L<1$ so choose $\epsilon$ such that $L+\epsilon, L-\epsilon <1$. Now applying the definition of limit to this $\epsilon$ and then applying recursion, you can see that $(L-\epsilon)^mx_N < x_{N+m}<(L+\epsilon)^m$. Now use the Sandwich Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

If $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}=L$, then for some $N$, $0<\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}<q\forall n>N$ where $q$ is some number between $L$ and $1$. (You can set $q$ as $L+\varepsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is small enough so that $L+\varepsilon<1$).

Now, notice that for all $n>N$, $0<x_{N+p}=\frac{x_{N+p}}{x_{N+p-1}}\cdot\frac{x_{N+p-1}}{x_{N+p-2}}\cdot\ldots\cdot\frac{x_{N+1}}{x_N}\cdot c<c\cdot q^{p}$

Where $c$ is a constant equal to $\frac{x_N}{x_{N-1}}\cdot\ldots\cdot\frac{x_2}{x_1}$

Taking the limit of the right side and noting that $|q|<1$, we find that the limit of the sequence $x_n$ is equal to $0$.

QED.

Answer (score 0):

Use inequality, 2nd form:
$$\Biggl\lvert\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}-L\Biggr\rvert\le\Biggl\lvert\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}-L\Biggr\rvert$$
If the latter is $<\varepsilon$ for all $n\ge N$, you deduce that:
$$0<\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}<L+\varepsilon,$$
hence if $L+\varepsilon\le k <1$, we have  $\,0<x_n<\dfrac{k^N}{x_N}k^{n}$,   i. e. if  $n$ is large enough , $x_n$ is bounded from above by a geometric sequence that converges to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

We can find an $N$ so that if $n\ge N$, we have $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\le\frac{L+1}2$. This means that for $n\ge N$, $x_n$ is a decreasing sequence bounded below by $0$. Therefore, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n$ exists and is $\ge0$.

Suppose that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x_\infty
$$
Taking the limit of
$$
x_{n+1}\le\frac{L+1}2x_n
$$
yields
$$
x_\infty\le\frac{L+1}2x_\infty
$$
Subtracting the right side from both sides and multiplying by $\frac2{1-L}$, which is positive, gives
$$
x_\infty\le0
$$
Therefore, $x_\infty=0$.